# How can I detect if the mouse is over an item/subitem in a List View control?

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I've searched around and haven't found a solution that sounds reasonable to me or that seems relevant to my specific problem (even here on Stack Overflow).

The problem is simple: I have most of the work needed to do custom checkboxes on any cell of a list view; I just need to detect hover on/hover off to draw the hot images. These images are set as the control's state image table, so I want to change the subitem state on hovers and clicks.

I tried using `NM_HOVER`, but after doing all the work to get things working it didn't work. Upon further research, it seems this is only issued if `LVS_EX_TRACKSELECT` is on, which I don't want; I just want to handle hovers, not select on hover!

I looked into using `NM_HOTTRACK` and `NM_ACTIVATE`, but that would only give me half the answer: I would not know when all items stop being hovered over (to cold-ify the last hot item).

I found some CodeProject project that does wacky things with internal tooltips. I don't want to touch internal data structures at all.

My List View is subclassed. I require Common Controls 6. I need to run on XP or newer (though a Vista-specific option is also acceptable for the future).

Do I have any options here? Thanks.

Comment: Well what are you trying to DO with the checkboxes?

Comment: If your listview is subclassed then you can access the message you need - `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: @colepanike: implement checkboxes on any column, not just the first :S

Comment: @JonathanPotter: hm, let's see...

Comment: @JonathanPotter wow I feel dumb now; not sure why I insisted on doing it "the right way" =P Though now I've run into another issue, maybe I'm misreading the docs: I set `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON` in the hit test info `flags` member, yet I get results throughout the item. Is `flags` actually an output value and I would need to set it to something else (or nothing at all) on input?

Comment: The `flags` field is set for you when `LVM_HITTEST` or `LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST` returns - you don't set it yourself.

Comment: All right, I think this question is answered =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the listview subclassed you can watch for `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages to detect the mouse moving over the control.

Depending on your requirements you may also want to use `TrackMouseEvent` to catch when the mouse leaves the window.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to need to do `TrackMouseEvent`; I just don't know if doing so will trample any private instances by the list view. We'll see. Thanks again!

Comment: As far as I know the listview only uses `TrackMouseEvent` if `LVS_EX_TRACKSELECT` is enabled although of course this could always change in the future.